# I have two tables and I want to select a new table where column A of table x is in column B of y

Tags: kdb

There are two tables, table A and table B.

```
Table A has columns `x`y`z
Table B has columns `o`p`q
```

I want to select a new table where

```
`x is in `o
```

(there could be multiple occurrences of that so a join does not help). UNEQUAL lengths as well.

This is in kdb.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the data from `A`:

```
select from A where x in exec distinct o from B
```